# Convert timestamp to X days X hours X minutes ago

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I've created a stored procedure in MySQL Server 5.1.

How can I convert a timestamp to a string that represents the days, hours, and minutes difference between that timestamp and now?

For example, if the timestamp is 5 hours and 3 minutes ago I'll get '5 hours 3 minutes ago'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select date_format(timediff(current_timestamp,last_timestamp), 
'%k hours, %i minutes, %s seconds ago');
```

If you want more luxury you can do something like:

```
select concat
  (
  if(date_format(timediff(ts1,ts2)'%k')='0'
     ,'',date_format(timediff(ts1,ts2)'%k hours'),
  if(date_format(timediff(ts1,ts2)'%i')='0'
     ,'',date_format(timediff(ts1,ts2)'%k minutes'),
  if(date_format(timediff(ts1,ts2)'%s')='0'
     ,'',date_format(timediff(ts1,ts2)'%k seconds')
  )
```

Plus a few extra spaces here and there.
If one of the timestamps is `null` naturally the result will also be null, you'll have to make sure it is not, or use `` ifnull(`timestamp`,now()) `` to fix that.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: i get NULL when i try to execute this function. besides that if it was created 3 minutes ago i don't want to be written 0 hours. only 3 minutes ago without the hours string.

Comment: Just a note that for time differences greater than ~35 days, the `TIMEDIFF` function will [only return a maximum of 838:59:59](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html). More information is presented in [this article](http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/getting-around-mysql-timediff-maximum-value-of-8385959/).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the MySQL reference page for date and time functions at

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Edit: Since I assume you are using Unix timestamps, the way to go is

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, format)
```